# What does ‘seething labyrinth’ mean in this sentence from an H.P. Lovecraft novel?

Tags: meaning-in-context, figurative-language

I would like ask for the meaning of phrase ‘*seething labyrinth*’ in sentence.

> ...in which he discerns a **seething labyrinth** housed in the range’s uppermost slopes...

It is from H.P. Lovecraft's novel  'At the Mountains of Madness', when the main protagonist is flying over the mountains and first time notices the unknown city situated at the top of that mountains.

As the word seething expresses the boiling process, but also can be a state of extreme agitation, especially through anger, is it possible to understand this concrete phrase as "*labyrinth shrouded in haze*" ?

Comment: Lovecraft is known for his dense prose and seemingly paradoxical adjectives. When you encounter a combination like this, don't try to understand it literally. Try to feel the mood instead.

Comment: Haze isn't 'extreme agitation', and seething can also refer to the confused movement of a crowd of people or animals. I would understand that the city was like a labyrinth (maze) and that its streets were very busy.

Comment: Jeffrey - I completely agree, mood is in lofcraftian proses a fundamental element of its atmosphere, i am trying  to translate this to other language, that´s why I am discussing - to translate it together with that mood.

Comment: Kate - So maybe the "pulsing labyrinth" could be more proper signification?